# Adding height constraint to UILabel issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, swift2

In Swift3 want to add height constraint 20px to UILabel but no luck, what I am missing?

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
```

this code works in Swift2.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One straight-forward way:

```
// assuming your UILabel is myLabel
myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
```